# smooth.Pspline wrapper for stat_smooth (in ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Sorry if this question is trivial, but I'm trying to figure out how to plot a certain type of natural cubic spline (NCS) in R and it's completely eluded me.

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214133/plotting-many-natural-cubic-splines-in-ggplot-r) I learned how to plot the NCS generated by the ns() command in ggplot, but I'm interested in how to plot a slightly different NCS generated the smooth.Pspline command in the [pspline](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pspline/index.html) package. As far as I know this is the only package that automatically selects the proper smoothing penalty by CV for a given dataset.

Ideally I would be able to provide smooth.Pspline as a method to a stat_smooth layer in ggplot2. My current code is like:

```
plot <- ggplot(data_plot, aes(x=age, y=wOBA, color=playerID, group=playerID))
plot <- plot + stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y~ns(x,4),se=FALSE)
```

I'd like to replace the "lm" formula with smooth.Pspline's functionality. I did a little bit of googling and found a [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/FJ36CJH-ODo) to the very similar B-spline function smooth.spline, written by Hadley. But I haven't been able to adapt this to smooth.Pspline perfectly. Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply need to inspect how `predict.smooth.Pspline` returns the predicted values.

In the internal workings of [`stat_smooth`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth.r), `predictdf` is called to create the smoothed line. `predictdf` is an internal (non-exported) function of `ggplot2` (it is defined [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth-methods.r)) it is a standard S3 method.

`sm.spline` returns an object of class `smooth.Pspline`, therefore for `stat_smooth` to work you need to create method for `predictdf` for class `smooth.Pspline`.

As such the following will work.

```
smP <- function(formula,data,...){
  M <- model.frame(formula, data)
  sm.spline(x =M[,2],y =M[,1])

}
# an s3 method for predictdf (called within stat_smooth)
predictdf.smooth.Pspline <- function(model, xseq, se, level) {
  pred <- predict(model, xseq)
  data.frame(x = xseq, y = c(pred))
}
```

An example (with a pspline fitted using `mgcv::gam` as comparison). `mgcv` is awesome and gives great flexibility in fitting methods and smoothing spline choices (although not CV, only GCV/UBRE/REML/ML)

```
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt))
d + geom_point() +  stat_smooth(method = smP, se= FALSE, colour='red', formula = y~x) + 
stat_smooth(method = 'gam', colour = 'blue', formula = y~s(x,bs='ps'))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what function or class dispatch principles result in `predictdf.smooth.Pspline` being called? And I didn't get it when Hadley wrote it and I don't see the connection here, either. I see that stat_smooth is supposed to return the same values as you are setting for the arguments of that function, but what determines how it is named or gets called?

Comment: I think I get it now. There are several built-in `predictdf` functions that will match a limited number of 'method's, but all you need to do to add one is match the name with the class returned by the 'method' argument.

Comment: Hi @mnel: Can I ask you a somewhat-stupid follow-up question? In the body of the `smP` method, is it possible to make available to `sm.spline(...)` a different column of the original dataset I'm plotting? In particular, I want to specify a weight to each point I'm plotting, and that weight is stored in a separate column of my dataset. It should be accessible from `M<-model.frame(formula,data)`, right?

Comment: @gogurt not easily, no. It might be better to use something like `dlply` or `by` to create the fits....

Comment: Hmm. That is a problem. Well, at least we're **most** of the way there. Thanks so much again!