# Can anyone explain more in detail preictdf() in geom_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to understand what lies behind geom_smooth() and what it does to predict the tendency line for my scatter plot. In the information says

> "Calculation is performed by the (currently undocumented) predictdf()
>   generic and its methods."

so I was wondering if anyone has more info about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rafael, this question is currently a bit vague, and could be interpreted as asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial"* ([off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Can you please ask specific questions where its behavior is not what you expect? It would help to make it a question with sample data/code (a minimal working example).

Comment: You can review the source on github: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth-methods.r

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [a blog post](https://eliocamp.github.io/codigo-r/2018/06/tu-propio-geom-smooth/) about using custom functions in geom_smooth that might be of help. It's in spanish, but I think google translate [does a decent job](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Feliocamp.github.io%2Fcodigo-r%2F2018%2F06%2Ftu-propio-geom-smooth%2F).

The gist of it is that the smoothing function has to take "formula", "data" and "weights" as arguments, plus any other that you need. It then needs to return an object that needs to have a `predictdf` method which takes "model", "xseq", "se", and "level" arguments. Where:
* Model is the object returned by your smoothing function, 
* xseq is a sequence of points in the x axis to evaluate the model,
* se is a logical indicating whether to plot the standard error, and
* level is the confidence level of said standard error.

The `predictdf` method should return a dataframe with x and y columns and, optionally, xmin and xmax (for the standard error).

Here's an example of a simple smoothing function that truncates the Fourier transform of a series. Note that it ignores most of the arguments passed either to the smoothing function or the `predictdf` method. They need to be there, however.

```r
library(ggplot2)

FFTSmooth <- function(formula, data, weights, n = 0.5) {
  f <- fft(data$y)
  keep <- c(0, seq_len(floor(length(f)/2*n)))
  keep <- c(keep + 1, length(f) - keep[keep != 0] + 1)
  f[-keep] <- 0 + 0i

  model <- list(x = data$x, pred = Re(fft(f, inverse = T))/length(f))
  class(model) <- "my_smooth"
  return(model)
}

predictdf.my_smooth <- function(model, xseq, se, level) {
  data.frame(x = model$x, y = model$pred)
}

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 360, length.out = 100))
df$y <- with(df, 5*cos(x*pi/180) + 3*sin(x*pi/180*3) + 1.6*rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "FFTSmooth", method.args = list(n = 0.2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ok. this is nice, but the question doesn't mention new methods, it seems to just want to understand the method it is currently applying.