# Add a Passing-Bablok regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, comparison

I have to perform many comparisons between different measurement methods and I have to use the [Passing-Bablok regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing%E2%80%93Bablok_regression) approach.

I would like to take advantage of `ggplot2` and faceting, but I don't know how to add a `geom_smooth` layer based on the Passing-Bablok regression.
I was thinking about something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173260/2096356

Furthermore, I would also need to show the regression line equation, with confidence interval for intercept and slope parameters, in each plot.

### Edit with partial solution

I've found a partial solution combining the code provided in [this post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passing%E2%80%93Bablok_regression) and [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173260/2096356).

```
## Regression algorithm
 passing_bablok.fit <- function(x, y) {
  
    x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  
    lx <- length(x)
    l <- lx*(lx - 1)/2
    k <- 0
    S <- rep(NA, lx)
    for (i in 1:(lx - 1)) {
      for (j in (i + 1):lx) {
        k <- k + 1
        S[k] <- (y[i] - y[j])/(x[i] - x[j])
      }
    }
    S.sort <- sort(S)
    N <- length(S.sort)
    neg <- length(subset(S.sort,S.sort < 0))
    K <- floor(neg/2)
    if (N %% 2 == 1) {
      b <- S.sort[(N+1)/2+K]
    } else {
      b <- sqrt(S.sort[N / 2 + K]*S.sort[N / 2 + K + 1])
    }
    a <- median(y - b * x)
    res <- as.vector(c(a,b))

  names(res) <- c("(Intercept)", x_name)
  class(res) <- "Passing_Bablok"
  res
}

## Computing confidence intervals
 passing_bablok <- function(formula, data, R = 100, weights = NULL){
  ret <- boot::boot(
    data = model.frame(formula, data), 
    statistic = function(data, ind) {
      data <- data[ind, ]
      args <- rlang::parse_exprs(colnames(data))
      names(args) <- c("y", "x")
      rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::expr(passing_bablok.fit(!!!args)), data, env = rlang::current_env())
    },
    R=R
  )
  class(ret) <- c("Passing_Bablok", class(ret))
  ret  
}

## Plotting confidence bands
 predictdf.Passing_Bablok <- function(model, xseq, se, level) {
  pred <- as.vector(tcrossprod(model$t0, cbind(1, xseq)))
  if(se) {
    preds <- tcrossprod(model$t, cbind(1, xseq))
    data.frame(
      x = xseq,
      y = pred,
      ymin = apply(preds, 2, function(x) quantile(x, probs = (1-level)/2)),
      ymax = apply(preds, 2, function(x) quantile(x, probs = 1-((1-level)/2)))
    )
  } else {
    return(data.frame(x = xseq, y = pred))
  }
}
```

An example of usage:

```
z <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 5), 
                y = rnorm(100, mean = 110, sd = 8))

ggplot(z, aes(x, y)) + 
 geom_point() + 
 geom_smooth(method = passing_bablok) + 
 geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0)
```

So far, I haven't been able to show the regression line equation, with confidence interval for intercept and slope parameters (as +- or in parentheses).

Comment: Hello! This question comes across to me like it's asking someone to just do all your work for you. You've been on this site a while now, so I think you already know that you are more likely to receive a useful answer if you provide a reproducible example and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Right, with some delay I've added a partial solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You've arguably done with difficult part with the PaBa regression.

Here's a basic solution using your `passing_bablok.fit` function:

```
z <- data.frame(x = 101:200+rnorm(100,sd=10),
                y = 101:200+rnorm(100,sd=8))

mycoefs <- as.numeric(passing_bablok.fit(x = z$x, y=z$y))

paba_eqn <-  function(thecoefs) {
  l <- list(m = format(thecoefs[2], digits = 2),
            b = format(abs(thecoefs[1]), digits = 2))
  if(thecoefs[1] >= 0){
    eq <- substitute(italic(y) == m %.% italic(x) + b,l)
  } else {
    eq <- substitute(italic(y) == m %.% italic(x) - b,l)    
  }
  as.character(as.expression(eq))
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(z, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = passing_bablok) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0) + 
  annotate("text",x = 110, y = 220, label = paba_eqn(mycoefs), parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

*Note the equation will vary because of `rnorm` in the data creation.*.

The solution could definitely be made more slick and robust, but it works for both positive and negative intercepts.

Equation concept sourced from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13451587/2651663