# How to transform data to fit diagonal line?

Tags: r, linear-regression

How do I transform the x and y values in a data frame, to fit the diagonal line? For example, given a data frame below, how do I 'rotate' the x and y values so the best fit line overlaps the diagonal line?

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100, 50, replace = T), y=sample(1:100, 50, replace = T))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = glm, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something? E.g. PCA?

Comment: Rotation of the coordinates is likely just a change in "basis" and is trigonometrically straight-forward and well-defined (just some matrix multiplication, tbh). Knowing what it should rotate to is likely something you want to know before sending to ggplot2, because ... well, if you need to do something with that regression line, then it's much harder to extract that conclusion from the `grob` than doing it yourself. While `geom_smooth` is a fantastic exploration tool, it should not be a replacement for determining your own statistics directly.

Comment: You could perform an "orthogonal regression," (as opposed to normal linear regression from `lm` / `geom_smooth`) which just minimizes errors in the dependent variable). I don't understand the math yet but I think PCA might also help with this or something close to it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004546/6851825

Comment: @r2evans rotating the line is fine, but OP is interested in transforming the data such that the line itself is rotated. This is not equivalent to rotating a line as there are errors involved. If the points were perfectly correlated, then the problem would break down to line rotation

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, I realized that this is more complicated than I expected. My problem is, I am comparing two plots where they have different regression line, and thus not directly comparable. That's why I think of converting everything to diagonal line. I will close this question and open a new one with this specific problem if there is no answer in a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to rotate the points by the angle between the regression line and the line *y = x* using geometrical methods, but it may not ultimately give you the result you are looking for.

Let's make a fully reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE), 
                 y = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = glm, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

We can work out the formula of the regression line using `lm`

```r
mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

summary(mod)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -53.982 -24.798   1.252  23.835  44.937 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  40.5140     8.9898   4.507 4.23e-05 ***
#> x             0.2275     0.1601   1.421    0.162    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 29.2 on 48 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.04036,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.02037 
#> F-statistic: 2.019 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 0.1618
```

Now we can use simple arithmetic to get the intersection between the regression line and the *y = x* line.

```r
crossing <- coef(mod)[1] / (1 - coef(mod)[2])
```

Now we can shift all our points by this amount to calculate the distance and angle of each of our points from the crossing point.

```r
df_centered <- df - crossing
r <- with(df_centered, sqrt(x^2 + y^2))
theta <- with(df_centered, atan2(y, x))
```

Now we get the angle by which we need to rotate our points

```r
rot <- atan(coef(mod)[2]) - atan(1)
```

Finally, we subtract this angle from the angle of each of the points, and calculate their new positions:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(x = cos(theta - rot) * r + crossing,
                  y = sin(theta - rot) * r + crossing)
```

These are the correctly rotated points.

We can demonstrate that these are the correct rotations by showing paths from the original (black) points to the rotated (red) points

```r
df3 <- data.frame(x = c(0, max(df$x)), 
                  y = c(0, max(df$x) * coef(mod)[2]) + coef(mod)[1],
                  id = 1:2) %>%
  transmute(theta = atan2(y - crossing, x - crossing),
            r = sqrt((y - crossing)^2 + (x - crossing)^2),
            id = id) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(x = cos(theta - seq(0, rot, len = 100)) * r + crossing,
          y = sin(theta - seq(0, rot, len = 100)) * r + crossing,
          id = id)

data.frame(theta = theta, r = r, id = seq_along(theta)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  reframe(x = cos(theta - seq(0, rot, len = 100)) * r + crossing,
          y = sin(theta - seq(0, rot, len = 100)) * r + crossing,
          id = id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group = id)) +
  geom_point(data = df) +
  geom_point(data = df2, color = "red") +
  geom_path(data = df3, aes(group = id), color = "blue", linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0, linetype = 2, color = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(data = df, method = "lm", se = FALSE, linetype = 2) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

The problem is that rotating your points like this will not result in the linear regression of the rotated points having a slope of one, because a linear regression minimizes the sum of squares of the *vertical* distances from the points to the regression line:

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = glm, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: indeed, the community made me realize that this is not the actual results I was aiming for. This answer is very insightful though and I will keep it for reference.